# Not able to retrieve record using eachRow method

Tags: mysql, sql, select, groovy, groovy-sql

I am using below groovy code to select a row with a given username and password from mysql db.

For example,

I am searching for below user. Password is stored in db as a SHA1 hashed password.

```
    Name - test7
password - {SHA}01132E914B722741CC3823D0BEACB8364EEAC376
```

Below is the groovy code which is trying to retrieve the record and failing as I am not able to fetch the record.I suspect the sql query constructed is wrong. SecurityUtil class is just decrypting and returning a plaintext password back as a positional parameter to the query. We are
using the sha1 method of mysql to generate the hash and prefix with string {SHA1} and then trying to retrieve the record.

```
sql.eachRow("SELECT id FROM users WHERE userName = ? AND password =CONCAT({SHA1},sha1(?))", [username, SecurityUtil.decrypt(password)]) {
authId = String.valueOf(it.id)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welp if SQL doesn't want to play do it in Groovy.  Using GStrings you get the same protection as prepared calls so no SQL Injection issues, and you can more easily do groovy operations:

```
sql.eachRow("SELECT id FROM users WHERE userName = ${userName} and password = ${'{SHA}' + SecurityUtil.decrypt(password)}") { 
    authId = String.valueOf( it.id )
}
```

The prepared statement syntax route:

```
sql.eachRow("SELECT id FROM users WHERE userName = ? and password = ?", [username, "{SHA}${SecurityUtil.descrypt(password)}"]) {
    authId = String.valueOf( it.id )
}
```

Comment: So, we are not supposed to use sha1() method of mysql if we do this by Groovy.

Comment: I don't follow what you are saying.  In your question you weren't using the MySQL Sha1 method.  All you were trying to do was concat a string onto the password.   I'm assuming suggesting just doing the concat in groovy if MySQL is being difficult.

Answer (score -1):

sql.eachRow("SELECT id FROM users WHERE userName = ? AND password =CONCAT(**'{SHA1}'**,sha1(?))", [username, SecurityUtil.decrypt(password)]) {
authId = String.valueOf(it.id)
}

You may need to put the {SHA} in quotes for use in the concat operator.

Comment: I tried within quotes, still query fails.